# Why is there no function to delete an event?

Tags: c++, windows

In Windows, I use CreateEvent or OpenEvent to use an event object, but I can't find a way to delete the object when I am finished with it.  Do I need to delete it?  If so, how do I do it?

Comment: CloseHandle https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most kernel objects (including event objects) are reference counted, so they do not need to be explicitly deleted.  When the last handle to the object is closed, the object is deleted automatically.

Notes:

- There is no way to force a kernel object to be deleted other than by closing the handle(s).
- Handles belong to the process that opens them, not the thread.  They can be used from any thread and are not automatically closed if the thread that opened them exits.
- When you launch a child process, there is an option for the child to inherit the handles of the parent process.  If this option is turned on, then any kernel objects your process had open at the time the child was launched will not be deleted until the child has exited.  (Unless of course the child explicitly closes the handles; usually this is not possible, because the child does not even know the handles exist.)

  If you need your child process to inherit certain handles, it is strongly recommended that you use the [`PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686880(v=vs.85).aspx) option so that the child only inherits those handles you explicitly specify.  For example, you can use this if you need to redirect the standard input and output.  If you don't specifically need any handles to be inherited, make sure you pass `FALSE` to the `bInheritHandles` parameter.
- If you will be using an object for the entire lifetime of your process, you do not need to close the handle; it will be closed automatically when the process terminates, and the corresponding object deleted if no other process has a handle to it.
- As an exception to the general rule, process objects and thread objects will be deleted only once all handles are closed *and* the corresponding process or thread has exited.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't **need** to delete the event. As @deviantfan mentioned in the comments, you can use [`CloseHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx) to signal that you are done with the object, but it's not necessary to do so. From [MSDN `CreateEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396(v=vs.85).aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Use the CloseHandle function to close the handle. The system closes the handle automatically when the process terminates. **The event object is destroyed when its last handle has been closed.**

Comment: But my handles are in service and the service only gets closed on system restart. 
If I don't close it keeps pilling up.